# Hibernate sort table based on max year and max month and group by id using criteria

Tags: mysql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I'm having difficulty representing this query which I write for select max month and max year rows from given 'uid'. I have 6 data in which 3 data has uid '4' and other 3 data has uid '5'. I want to get the max month and max year data from both uid 4 and 5. Here is my criteria query I get the this result.

> Size of result list: 2
>   uID: 5    nID: cdf    Month: 11    Year: 2012
>   uID: 4    nID: f58    Month: 10    Year: 2012

But when i change year of uid from 2012 to 2013 it only returns uid 4's row only.

```
DetachedCriteria maxYearQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Demo.class);
        ProjectionList yearProj = Projections.projectionList();
        yearProj.add(Projections.max("contextYear"));
        yearProj.add(Projections.max("contextMonth"));
        yearProj.add(Projections.groupProperty("entityUUID"));
        maxYearQuery.setProjection(yearProj);

    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Demo.class);
            crit.add(Subqueries.propertiesIn(new String[] {"contextYear","contextMonth", "entityUUID"}, maxYearQuery));
            crit.addOrder(Order.desc("entityUUID"));
```

my table is looks like this..

>

uID: 4    nID: cdf    Month: 10    Year: 2012

uID: 4    nID: f58    Month: 9    Year: 2012

uID: 5    nID: f58    Month: 8    Year: 2012

uID: 5    nID: f58    Month: 11    Year: 2012

uID: 5    nID: f58    Month: 10    Year: 2013

uID: 4    nID: f58    Month: 9    Year: 2012

I want the 1st and 5th record from my database. I am stuck at this stage. Please give some guidance to get record by grouping.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want this type of query

Select Max(month),Max(Year) from Demo group by uid;

Comment: Thanks Dheeraj and Yes , I want same type of query. The above query is work well but for same year. When I change year it returns only one result.

Comment: It should return whole object not only max month and year.

Answer (score 0):

i find solution of your problem

Supose name of table is Demo and in which three column uid,month ,year

Query:

select a.uid,a.year,max(month) from Demo a inner join(select uid,max(year) m from Demo group by 1) d on a.uid=d.uid and a.year=d.m group by 2;

It will work fine check it and give me feedback

Comment: Hey Dheeraj thanks for the query. However I wanted it using criteria only.